# How to access options inside apos.define?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apostrophe-cms

`apostrophe-workflow` has the following:

public/js/user.js

```
apos.define('apostrophe-workflow', {

  [...]

  construct: function(self, options) {

    self.locales = options.locales;
    self.locale = options.locale;
    [...]
```

I searched quite a while and did not manage to find the reason why this construct method has access to the `options` object. I tried `browserCall` but am not sure how to use this properly.

My assets are pushed using `pushAsset`, too. But they do not have access to the options after `apos.create`.

**Edit: Example scenario:**

A simple module that pushes one script to the browser.

module/index.js

```
construct: function(self, options) {
  self.pushAsset('script', 'name', {when: 'always'});
}
```

And takes one option.

app.js

```
modules: {
  'module': {
    option: 'Option'
  }
}
```

The script should use this option on `construct`.

module/public/js/script.js

```
apos.define('module-script', {
  construct: function(self, options) {
    console.log(options.option); // Print 'Option' to console.
  }
});
```

Another module will call `apos.create('module-script')`.

I hope it's clear.

Comment: You are trying to get options from a module's config to the browser side, yes?

Comment: Yes. The way you showed me in the last question helped a lot. But I wonder what's going on here? There is no `apos.modules['name'].options`.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve (at least) this two ways depending on the structure you want.

### **1. Explicit browser options**

You can explicitly pass options to the browser from your modules configuration by wrapping them in a `browser` object from the root of the module's config.

in `lib/modules/layout-widgets/index.js`

```
module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
    label: 'Layout',
    browser: {
      coolArray: [3, 2, 1]
    }
  }
```

This will get merged into the options passed to your browser side JS of the module automatically.

then in `/lib/modules/layout-widgets/public/js/always.js`

```
apos.define('layout-widgets', {
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
  construct: function (self, options) {
    self.play = function ($widget, data, options) {
      console.log(self.options.coolArray);
    }
  }
});
```

### 2. Super'ing `getCreateSingletonOptions`

If you don't like the syntax of separating your browser options from your main options, you can always override the method responsible for teeing up the browser side module's default options by copying it, invoking it, and adding on to it.

in `lib/modules/layout-widgets/index.js`

```
module.exports = {        
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',        
  label: 'Layout',
  coolArray: [3,2,1],
  construct: function(self, options) {

    // copy the method
    var superGetCreateSingletonOptions = self.getCreateSingletonOptions;

    // redefine it
    self.getCreateSingletonOptions = function (req) {

      // invoke the original method and save the result
      var browserOptions = superGetCreateSingletonOptions(req);

      // add on to the default results with whatever you want
      browserOptions.coolArray = self.options.coolArray;
      browserOptions.somethingElse = 'hey this is fun';

      return browserOptions;
    };
  }
};
```

then, again, in `/lib/modules/layout-widgets/public/js/always.js`

```
apos.define('layout-widgets', {
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
  construct: function (self, options) {
    self.play = function ($widget, data, options) {
      console.log(self.options.coolArray);
      console.log(self.options.somethingElse);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but this doesn't work for me. To clarify things:

- I do not have a widget.
- The browser side `options` returns an empty object and `self.options` is not defined.
- Tried both methods you described.
- `apostrophe-workflow` itself does not use `self.options` nor `self.play` and the `options` object is not empty.

What does `apostrophe-workflow` do to have this `options` object filled?

Comment: oof, sorry about that, I will dig around

Comment: The method Stuart is recommending works for the browser-side module singletons. If you are not creating a browser singleton, we'll need to know more about what your object is and where it fits into Apostrophe's ecosystem in order to help you. I would recommend sharing a simple demo project.

Comment: `construct` receives `options` because that's what moog does with the options object passed to `apos.create`. As for how and when `apos.create` is called and with what options, we need to know more about your code. Is this a module singleton? A pieces editor modal? Something else?

Comment: Updated question.