# How to get the current locale in apostrophecms js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, apostrophe-cms

I have js file in public folder of one of my module. I want the current selected locale in same file. Where file has defination

`apos.define('test-widgets', { 
  improve: 'test-widgets',
  construct: function (self, options) {
  }
}`.

Inside this definition there is constructor also.

I can get the locale label using `data.workflow.locales['fr'].label` in html file but same thing I can't get in public js file.

Thank you for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this by referring

> [How to access options inside apos.define?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51030428/how-to-access-options-inside-apos-define)

Thanks to @stuart-romanek for great help!